# Does California maintain its own record of minor traffic tickets incurred by out-of-state drivers?

Tags: california, driving, interstate-travel

Convictions for reportable moving violations in California are reported to the CA DMV [1]. For drivers licensed in California, this will result in a number of points, dependent on the specific violation, being assigned to the driver's record [2]. However, if the driver is not licensed in California, the violation will be reported to the state in which he/she is licensed [3], and certain states do not assess points for minor out-of-state violations (e.g. MA [4], PA [5]).

In the case of a driver licensed in one of these states being convicted of such a minor moving violation in California, does California maintain its own record, so that if the driver subsequently moves to California and becomes licensed there, these points would be applied to his or her record?

Unfortunately I cannot directly link to the cited sources above due to lack of reputation. Instead, I have collected relevant links in a GitHub Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78e138229621ed237ede0c80696fbd8c). I'd be grateful if someone could edit these into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

California may attempt to report your violation to your state's DMV. When you move into the state and attempt to obtain your California license, the state of California will attempt to check the DMV record of the state you are emigrating from.

California probably also maintains a local database of violations for out of state violators (they retain your driving record if you move out of state and then move back - you will even be assigned the same Driver's License number,) however the statute of limitations for traffic violations is 5 years and violations over 5 years old can be removed from your record. These may be removed automatically, or you may need to contact the [Mandatory Action Unit](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/dl/authority#amend) in Sacremento to have your driving record amended.